# 400 error when running npm install related to GitHub

Tags: github, npm, installation

I use two Github platform. The public one at https://github.com and my work enterprise one https://github.work.com.

I haven't had any trouble before but I'm trying to run `npm install`. The project has a package.json file which contains a dependency which is references a repository in my work in git:

```
"my-dependency-sdk": "git+https://git@github.work.com:organization/my-dependency-sdk.git"
```

This is the output from the install:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/local/bin/git ls-remote -h -t https://git@github.work.com/:organization/my-dependency-sdk.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! fatal: unable to access 'https://git@github.work.com/:organization/my-dependency-sdk.git/': The requested URL returned error: 400
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2018-04-10T17_44_59_498Z-debug.log
```

Is it possible that the Git installation on my Mac holds some configuration that may be pointing to the public Github and the repository I'm looking for isn't there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL was incorrect. It should have been:

```
git+https://github.work.com/organization/my-dependency-sdk.git
```

The format I originally used was for ssh.